# How to pass the result of a Future as a parameter to a non-Future provider

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, riverpod

I'm facing a challenge in my Flutter project with RiverPod. My goal is to pass the result of a `FutureProvider` to a regular provider, but I'm encountering a type mismatch issue.

**The Problem:**
I have a `FutureProvider` that asynchronously obtains `SharedPreferences`, and I need to use its result as a parameter in another provider, which is a regular provider, not a `FutureProvider`. Here's a snippet of my code:

```dart
class ProfileRepository {
  final SharedPreferences prefs;

  ProfileRepository({required this.prefs});

  // rest of the methods
}

@riverpod
Future<SharedPreferences> sharedPreferences(SharedPreferencesRef ref) async {
  return await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
}

@riverpod
ProfileRepository profileRepository(ProfileRepositoryRef ref) {
  final prefs = ref.watch(sharedPreferencesProvider); // Returns AsyncValue<SharedPreferences>
  return ProfileRepository(prefs: prefs); // Error here
}
```

In this setup, `sharedPreferencesProvider` is a `FutureProvider` that fetches `SharedPreferences`. I want to pass the fetched `SharedPreferences` instance to `ProfileRepository`. However, `ref.watch(sharedPreferencesProvider)` gives me an `AsyncValue<SharedPreferences>`, not a `SharedPreferences` instance. As a result, I'm getting the following error:

```
The argument type 'AsyncValue<SharedPreferences>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'SharedPreferences'.
```

**What I've Tried:**

- I considered converting `profileRepository` into a `FutureProvider`, but it would significantly change the existing architecture, which I prefer to avoid.
- I'm not sure how to extract the actual `SharedPreferences` instance from `AsyncValue<SharedPreferences>` in the context of a non-async provider.

**My Question:**
How can I correctly pass the result of the `FutureProvider` (the `SharedPreferences` instance) to the `ProfileRepository` provider in RiverPod? Is there an alternative approach or pattern that would be better suited for this scenario?

Any advice or guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a provider to hold the instance of `SharedPreferences`. Instead, initialize that in `main`, and provide a global "prefs". Then, all shared preferences access is sync for reading.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing right now, but it makes me feel "dirty" in a way. Isn't there a better way to approach this or is this the "go to" approach?

Comment: It's what I first reach for.  The only alternate I would suggest is that if you need to "mock" prefs for testing, you can put it in a sync provider that you initialize in a ProviderContainer in main, or then override in tests.

Comment: _"provide a global "prefs"_ as in a Global `static` `SharedPreferences`?

Comment: In dart, they're just "globals", because we're not Java... we have top-level non-class objects.